# Listing all unique class name that begin with a prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, list, css-selectors

Well, lets see a markup as an example.

```
<div class="_round_5">Some text</div>
<div class="_brTop_5">Another Text</div>
```

<sub>My idea is to collect all the unique class name in a page that begin with a `_` and post them to a different page, which will return me with a file that contains a generated CSS style based on those class name</sub>.

Now, How to collect all the **unique** class names that begin with a "_" or some other prefix also? The list might be an array or json. But I prefer json.

Comment: How should `<div class="_round_51234 _bla4536456">` be handled? Should it even be accounted for?

Comment: @thirtydot, yes, anything that begins with a "_", must be accounted for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try: http://jsfiddle.net/54kzu/3/

It correctly handles multiple classes, as you requested in the comments.

```
var uniqueClasses = [];

$('[class]').each(function() {
    var thisClasses = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
    $.each(thisClasses, function(i, thisClass) {
        if (thisClass.substring(0,1) == '_' && $.inArray(thisClass, uniqueClasses) == -1) {
            uniqueClasses.push(thisClass);
        }
    });
});

console.log(uniqueClasses);
```

Comment: Wow, just superb (+1).But, one tread. What are the performance effects of this code?

Comment: It's not awesome (thanks to the nested `.each`, and having to inspect *every* element [but I don't see a way around that]), but you'll never notice it with normal-sized pages. For running just once (as I presume is the case), it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Furthermore, I found a limitation in the snippet you provided. Provided my markup was this `<div class="4_round _5_bla">Some text</div>`, since the class attribute does not begin with `_`, it ignores `_5_bla` which should be accounted. How to come around this bump?

Comment: Good catch. Try this updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/54kzu/3/ - now we're looking for any element with a `class` attribute. For each class within, see if it starts with `_`. If it does, and it's not already in the list, add it to the list.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [**Start Selector**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: Selection is not quite my solution. I knew that...but I want to grab all the names as quickly as possible, also unique ones.